# Elixir - Call gen server from another node

Tags: elixir, nodes, gen-server

I have two nodes on my pc (`foo@my-pc` and `bar@my-pc`).
The `bar` node has a simple gen-server in it:

```
defmodule Bar.Server do
  use ExActor.GenServer, export: :bar_server
  defstart start_link, do: initial_state(0)
  defcall get, state: state, do: reply(state)
  defcast(set(num), state: state, do: new_state(state + num))
end
```

The Genserver is started and running 
so when i run :

```
GenServer.call(:bar_server, :get)
```

it perfectly works.
I connected `foo` to `bar` by running in foo `Node.connect :'bar@my-pc'`
and what i expected was that now `foo` will be familiar with the genserver `:aa` in `bar`,
But - when i run

```
GenServer.call(:bar_server, :get)
```

i get:

```
 (EXIT) no process: the process is not alive or there's no process currently associated with the given name, possibly because its application isn't started
```

I'm assuming i am missing something. but can figure out what.

Comment: Does this work: `GenServer.call({:bar_server, :'bar@my-pc'}, :get)`?

Comment: yes i does. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you only want a single instance of the GenServer running between the two nodes, you need to explicitly register the GenServer as global:

```
use ExActor.GenServer, export: {:global, :bar_server}
```

To communicate with this process, use the same name:

```
GenServer.call({:global, :bar_server}, :get)
```

Besides `:global` there are a couple of other options to register GenServer names across nodes. See the [Name Registration](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#module-name-registration) part of the GenServer documentation for details.

Comment: Is this suppose to work when connecting two nodes in the same cluster (on kubernetes). because for some reason i keep getting that error `no process... ` when trying to reach the genserver. ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that you need to call using `GenServer.call({:global, :bar_server}, :get)`

Comment: How do you handle when there are multiple instances of Gen server running on a single machine?

Answer (score 0):

You register a process to make it singleton: making it available as only instance.

If you give it a name with “name: processname” then you can not register another process with the same name on that node.

If you need multiples of a process, then you may use a supervisor to get a child of that process, use it and ask the supervisor to terminate the child once done with.

This design pattern will help you manage the children via supervisor, in case the child processes crash.

Answer (score 0):

I am still new so I'm not sure if it will work, but I think you should simply spawn a process on bar from foo that executes the GenServer.call(). Since it is executed on bar, it will find the GenServer and be able to execute the call then, the reply will be returned to foo.
I based my answer on this link: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.16/distributed-tasks.html

So just run this on foo@my-pc:

```
Node.spawn_link(:"foo@my-pc", fn -> GenServer.call(:bar_server, :get) end)
```